# tcpdf generates .html document in safari and opera

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf with Cakephp. The PDFs are downloaded good in Linux but when it comes to Mac for Opera and Safari it add .html ectension to it.

I also noticed that even if it downloads as PDF document in FireFox and Google Chrome, the Pop-up to save as reads it as "HTML document" but save as PDF. PLease help me with this.

Comment: Are the PDFs output from the *Controller* or inside a *View*? What version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: Yes Outputs are inside View itself. Cakephp version is 2.1.5

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify headers, like:

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file_name));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header("Cache-Control: private", false); // required for certain browsers
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_name));
```

Hope it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Mac and Safari are more strict when it comes to mime types, and always obeys the content type set in your scripts. So if the Content type is being set to text/html, Safari will expect it to be a HTML document and add the html extension.  Firefox and Chrome are using this content-type header to present the file type (HTML document), but does not change the filename so it saves as a PDF.

As you are using CakePHP, it's a good idea to use the built in file response in your Controller:

```
$this->response->file($path,array('download' => true, 'name' => $filename));
return $this->response;
```

This will correctly set the headers you need for most files. See here for docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files

Be warned, CakePHP might not know the mimetype of some files, and will default to text/html.  Then you'll get the same problem in Safari.  It's a good idea to test and if you see this happening, set the mime types yourself (BEFORE setting the file):

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
switch ($ext) {
    case 'dotx':
        $this->response->type('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template');
    break;
}
$this->response->file($path,array('download' => true, 'name' => $filename));
return $this->response;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found by adding

```
$this->response->type('application/pdf');
```

to the view file **and** by updating to the latest version of the TCPDF vendor files it resolved the same issue for us (as well as other display issues).

Answer (score 0):

In your controller simply add this

```
$this->response->header(array('Content-type: application/pdf')); 
$this->response->type('pdf');
```

By adding this same issue is solved to me.